# Fast Byte Array Deserialization

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I have the following code that deserializes byte arrays to Event objects but it is too slow for me. I have thousands of these Events and creating new input streams for each object seems time consuming. Note that the byte arrays come from Kafka and, hence, I don't have a single huge array to create the two input streams only once.

```
override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): Event = {
    val in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val is = new ObjectInputStream(in)
    is.readObject.asInstanceOf[Event]
}
```

Comment: Beside the speed there are a lot of reasons to don't use standard Java serialization. [Here](https://github.com/dkomanov/scala-serialization/pull/8) are result of comparison of different serialization libraries for Scala with binary and text representation which do parsing and serialization much faster.

Comment: Java serialization is notoriously slow, the issue is not allocating a new input stream (but if you have measurements to share in this regard, I'm happy to stand corrected). If you have the freedom of doing so, I would suggest you look into other serialization formats designed to be more performant and (more importantly) having features that make your life easier when it comes to evolving your schema. Avro is a fairly accepted standard among Kafka users and it's natively supported by Confluent's schema registry for Kafka. You may want to have a look at these tools.